# Javascript play() after requestFullScreen not working on video

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, fullscreen

I am requesting full screen on button click for `<video>`, but the thing is that the play() function does not work when `requestFullScreen()` is used.

Any idea why not?

Code:

```
video[0].play();
if(video[0].requestFullScreen) {
  video[0].requestFullScreen();
} else if(video[0].mozRequestFullScreen) {
  video[0].mozRequestFullScreen();
} else if(video[0].webkitRequestFullScreen) {
  video[0].webkitRequestFullScreen();
}
```

Comment: Is there an error in the console? Or just no effect? does full screen work?

Comment: No error in console, and fullscreen works if I do not call play() and viceversa.

Comment: Works okay for me (Chrome & Firefox). http://jsbin.com/oguqub/1/edit Is there something weird with your video encode?

Comment: That example doesn't work on My Mac in Chrome

Comment: Sorry, full screen doesn't work in jsbin in the iframe.  You have to pop it out. Try this one: http://jsbin.com/oguqub/1/

Comment: Would it be anything to do with whether controls are enabled or not?

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference. You can try it by right-clicking the video and enabling controls with the pop-up menu. Works the same for me. (OSX 10.7.5 & Chrome 27)